# How to replay current frame when mouse out on flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is what I have got so far:

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playMovie); function playMovie(event) { play(); }
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopMovie); function stopMovie(event) { gotoAndStop(0);}


stop();
```

And I am look for instead of "gotoAndStop" a reverse kind of function from the current frame

Thanks

Max

Comment: What do you mean by reverse function from the current frame?

Comment: Replay back to the first frame.

Comment: go in reverse back to the start?

Comment: yes. Sorry I am a bit of a rookie

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it:

```
//a function you can call and pass in the item/timeline you want played backwards
function goBackwards(item:MovieClip):void {
    item.stop(); //make sure the item isn't playing before starting frame handler below
    item.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBackwards); //add a frame handler that will run the moveBackwards function once every frame
}

//this function will move something one frame back everytime it's called
function moveBackwards(e:Event):void {
    var m:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip; //get the movie clip that fired the event
    if(m.currentFrame > 1){ //check to see if it's already back to the start
        m.prevFrame();  //if not move it one frame back
    }else{
        m.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBackwards); //if it is (at the start), remove the enter frame listener so this function doesn't run anymore
    }
}
```

So if your object you want to play backwards is called `bob`, you would do this:  `goBackwards(bob);`.  If you wanted to use it within the timeline you want to play backwards, do `goBackwards(this);`.

Comment: How are you using the code?  I added usage examples at the end of the answer

Comment: where do you put "goBackwards(this);" ? 2nd line?

Comment: is pretty shabby a good thing?  you put `goBackward(this)`  (as well as the rest of the code) on whatever timeline you want to go backwards.

Comment: No, bad thing haha. What is the "timeline"? do you mean layer? and is bob the instance name?

Comment: not sure what you calling shabby then. The timeline is the thing your layers are on.  Every movieClip has a timeline (including your root, which is the main timeline of your project).  timelines consist of keyframes, where you put code and/or symbols (graphical assets).

Comment: @user1857312 that's pretty rude.  LondonDrugs gave you a sound answer with examples. Calling it shabby because you don't understand how it works is.. well... rude!

Comment: I am so sorry! I misread LondonDrugs I thought you said "How are you using code?" Which I said pretty shabby (as in I am rubbish at using the code behind flash) instead of "How are you using the code?"

Comment: @user1857312 - no worries, I would recommend you do some basic flash tutorials that can familiarize you with the basics like the timeline, and instances of library assets.

Comment: I will do! Are you definite that the code works? I have been  fiddling with code for ages! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far! You know when you double click my image turns into a bitmap? which is really anoying because then i can't do my blur effect am i suposed to convert to symbol again?

Comment: it's ok to have symbols within symbols. so yes, have your image as it's own symbol, then have it within your animation symbol